# Suppress Column data if data is already in another column

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a report I need to submit that has an owners address and a project address. I only need to show the owners address if it is different from the project address. I need to show all the project addresses though. I tried suppressing if it was same but it just hides it. Is there a way to write a formula to hide if the same as another column?

Comment: can you explain `I tried suppressing if it was same but it just hides it`?

Comment: I Think I wrote the formula wrong. I wrote it as Supress if {owneraddress}={propertyaddress}

It then suppresses the data it only shows results where the addresses are different. 

I'm trying to show all the address but only show the owners address if it is different from the property address.

Comment: are owner address and property address are different fields? or in same field?

Answer (score 0):

Place two fields in the report and on owners address field write the supress condtion.. I guess you wrote on the section which is supressing both which is creating the problem.

Let me know if you are looking for something different.